# How to calculate the accumulated time of a groupby function using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

everyone! I have the following dataset (https://pastebin.com/697NsZXk):

```
dfA
Out[83]: 
                    time     Var1    Y1  Class1  flagA
2070 2020-09-15 10:30:00  66.3260  59.6  A-8444      1
2071 2020-09-15 10:31:00  66.2881  59.6  A-8444      1
2072 2020-09-15 10:32:00  66.2570  59.6  A-8444      1
2073 2020-09-15 10:33:00  66.2364  59.6  A-8444      1
2074 2020-09-15 10:34:00  66.2511  59.6  A-8444      1
2075 2020-09-15 10:35:00  66.2478  59.6  A-8444      1
2076 2020-09-15 10:36:00  66.2571  59.6  A-8444      1
2077 2020-09-15 10:37:00  66.2645  59.6  A-8444      1
2078 2020-09-15 10:38:00  66.2233  59.6  A-8444      1
2079 2020-09-15 10:39:00  66.2132  59.6  A-8444      1
                 ...      ...   ...     ...    ...
3501 2020-09-16 10:21:00  58.8167  59.3  A-8448      1
3502 2020-09-16 10:22:00  59.1132  59.3  A-8448      1
3503 2020-09-16 10:23:00  59.4533  59.3  A-8448      1
3504 2020-09-16 10:24:00  59.7931  59.3  A-8448      1
3505 2020-09-16 10:25:00  60.1398  59.3  A-8448      1
3506 2020-09-16 10:26:00  60.5043  59.3  A-8448      1
3507 2020-09-16 10:27:00  60.8606  59.3  A-8448      1
3508 2020-09-16 10:28:00  61.2513  59.3  A-8448      1
3509 2020-09-16 10:29:00  61.6430  59.3  A-8448      1
3510 2020-09-16 10:30:00  62.0610  59.3  A-8448      1

[1441 rows x 5 columns]
```

And I would like to calculate the average, min and max for Var1 and Y1, grouping by ['Class1','flagA']. I was able to do that using the code below, but I also want to calculate the accumulated time between each "group". For example, the result a got was:

```
                     Var1                        Y1              
                 amin     amax    average  amin  amax average
Class1 flagA                                                 
A-8444 0      26.6498  49.8490  34.371305  59.6  59.6    59.6
       1      50.0507  67.0296  63.722390  59.6  59.6    59.6
A-8445 0      27.0750  49.8547  36.590446  59.7  59.7    59.7
       1      50.1771  67.0874  63.562250  59.7  59.7    59.7
A-8446 0      26.2272  49.4617  33.005098  59.4  59.4    59.4
       1      50.2412  67.1156  63.853893  59.4  59.4    59.4
A-8448 0      25.6820  49.6583  33.084543  59.3  59.3    59.3
       1      50.0283  62.0610  56.053144  59.3  59.3    59.3
```

But I still need another column showing how much time interval each group represents. Any ideas? It would be **something like that**:

```
                 Var1                        Y1              
                 amin     amax    average  amin  amax average  **accumulated time**
Class1 flagA                                                 
A-8444 0      26.6498  49.8490  34.371305  59.6  59.6    59.6    **hh:mm:ss**
       1      50.0507  67.0296  63.722390  59.6  59.6    59.6    **hh:mm:ss**
A-8445 0      27.0750  49.8547  36.590446  59.7  59.7    59.7    **hh:mm:ss**
       1      50.1771  67.0874  63.562250  59.7  59.7    59.7    **hh:mm:ss**
A-8446 0      26.2272  49.4617  33.005098  59.4  59.4    59.4    **hh:mm:ss**
       1      50.2412  67.1156  63.853893  59.4  59.4    59.4    **hh:mm:ss**
A-8448 0      25.6820  49.6583  33.084543  59.3  59.3    59.3    **hh:mm:ss**
       1      50.0283  62.0610  56.053144  59.3  59.3    59.3    **hh:mm:ss**
```

current code:

```
#Creating flagA
conditions = [
(dfA['Var1'] < 50),
(dfA['Var1'] >= 50)
]
values = [0, 1]
dfA.loc[:,'flagA'] = np.select(conditions, values)

#groupby to calculate min, max and average. Need to add something to calculate accumulated time.
teste = dfA.groupby(['Class1','flagA']).agg([np.min, np.max, np.average])
```

Comment: can you provide example output of the column you want?

Comment: Hi, Vivek. Thanks for your help, I think @piterbarg sent us the answer down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make sure 'time' is actyually of type `datetime` not `str`:

```
dfA['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['time'])
```

Then we can apply max and min aggregators to `time`. Since we cannot do `np.min` on datetime we can replace with `min`, same for max. But there is no `average` that can be used for both floats and datetimes. so we need to be a a bit more specific as to what aggregation functions to apply to what columns/ Replace your groupby with

```
teste = dfA.groupby(['Class1','flagA']).agg({'time':[min, max], 'Var1':[min, max, np.average], 'Y1':[min, max, np.average]})
```

and then we can use max time and min time to calculate accumulated time as such:

```
teste['accumulated time'] = teste[('time','max')] - teste[('time','min')]
```

we get something like this, which I assume is what you want (or close enough)

````
|               | ('time', 'min')     | ('time', 'max')     |   ('Var1', 'min') |   ('Var1', 'max') |   ('Var1', 'average') |   ('Y1', 'min') |   ('Y1', 'max') |   ('Y1', 'average') | ('accumulated time', '')   |
|:--------------|:--------------------|:--------------------|------------------:|------------------:|----------------------:|----------------:|----------------:|--------------------:|:---------------------------|
| ('A-8444', 0) | 2020-09-15 11:28:00 | 2020-09-15 19:51:00 |           26.6498 |           49.849  |               34.3713 |            59.6 |            59.6 |                59.6 | 0 days 08:23:00            |
| ('A-8444', 1) | 2020-09-15 10:30:00 | 2020-09-15 18:40:00 |           50.0507 |           67.0296 |               63.7224 |            59.6 |            59.6 |                59.6 | 0 days 08:10:00            |
| ('A-8445', 0) | 2020-09-15 19:52:00 | 2020-09-16 02:30:00 |           27.075  |           49.8547 |               36.5904 |            59.7 |            59.7 |                59.7 | 0 days 06:38:00            |
| ('A-8445', 1) | 2020-09-15 21:17:00 | 2020-09-16 02:01:00 |           50.1771 |           67.0874 |               63.5622 |            59.7 |            59.7 |                59.7 | 0 days 04:44:00            |
| ('A-8446', 0) | 2020-09-16 02:31:00 | 2020-09-16 03:59:00 |           26.2272 |           49.4617 |               33.0051 |            59.4 |            59.4 |                59.4 | 0 days 01:28:00            |```
````

Answer (score 1):

Group them together to find the minimum and maximum time. Combine them together to create a multiple data frame. Then we find the differences between the minimum and maximum times and convert them into a time format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfA = pd.read_csv('./Data/697NsZXk.csv', sep=',')
teste = dfA.groupby(['Class1','flagA']).agg([np.min, np.max, np.average])
dfA['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['time'])
ts_min = dfA.groupby(['Class1','flagA'])['time'].min()
ts_max = dfA.groupby(['Class1','flagA'])['time'].max()
ts = pd.concat([ts_min,ts_max], axis=1)
ts.columns = ['ts_min', 'ts_max']
ts['ts_delta'] = ts['ts_max'] - ts['ts_min']
final = pd.concat([teste, ts[['ts_delta']]], axis=1)
final['ts_delta'] = final['ts_delta'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x.total_seconds() // 3600))+':'+ str(int(x.total_seconds() % 3600 // 60)))

final
    (Var1, amin)    (Var1, amax)    (Var1, average) (Y1, amin)  (Y1, amax)  (Y1, average)   ts_delta
Class1  flagA                           
A-8444  0   26.6498 49.8490 34.371305   59.6    59.6    59.6    8:23
1   50.0507 67.0296 63.722390   59.6    59.6    59.6    8:10
A-8445  0   27.0750 49.8547 36.590446   59.7    59.7    59.7    6:38
1   50.1771 67.0874 63.562250   59.7    59.7    59.7    4:44
A-8446  0   26.2272 49.4617 33.005098   59.4    59.4    59.4    1:28
1   50.2412 67.1156 63.853893   59.4    59.4    59.4    4:30
A-8448  0   25.6820 49.6583 33.084543   59.3    59.3    59.3    1:20
1   50.0283 62.0610 56.053144   59.3    59.3    59.3    0:38
```